# Configured truststore path in Spark Cassandra connector returns NoSuchFileException

Tags: apache-spark, ssl, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using Datastax Spark Cassandra Connector for my PySpark application (in `.master("yarn")` session mode).

But our security rules require that I should connect to Cassandra only with SSL connection. As I was told, our Cassandra does not verify its clients (only checks username/password pairs), but we, the clients, should verify Cassandra with SSL certificates.

I was given a path to JKS trust store that and wanted to pass it to Datastax Spark Connector.

I set the following SparkSession parameters:

```
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabled: true
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.clientAuth.enabled: false
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.path: "/home/tech_profiling/mdp-cassandra-keystore.jks"
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.password: "cassandra"
spark.cassandra.auth.username: "my_super_dooper_gigachad_user"
spark.cassandra.auth.username: "my_mega_password"
```

I checked that this file `/home/tech_profiling/mdp-cassandra-keystore.jks` is really present on my Spark cluster nodes. But anyway it gives me the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o486.save.
: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/tech_profiling/mdp-cassandra-keystore.jks
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.getKeyStore(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:78)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.trustStore$lzycompute$1(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:92)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.trustStore$1(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:91)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.maybeCreateSSLOptions(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:97)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.clusterBuilder(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:62)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createCluster(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:131)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:159)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$8.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:154)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$8.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:154)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:32)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.syncAcquire(RefCountedCache.scala:69)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:57)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:79)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.dht.TokenFactory$.forSystemLocalPartitioner(TokenFactory.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation$.apply(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Has anyone already encountered with such a problem?

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the jks file? Depending on how you're running the application, the user may not be what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

That exception indicates that the Spark executors are not able to access the file.

We recommend using the `spark.files` option ( or `--files`) since Spark will distribute the specified files to all the executors' working directory.

For example, you would pass `/home/tech_profiling/mdp-cassandra-keystore.jks` to `spark.files` then configure the truststore path with:

```
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.path: keystore.jks
```

Cheers!